# Why does SELECT 'foo' + NULL; returns NULL on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-null

Why does `SELECT 'foo' + NULL;` returns `NULL` on SQL Server? I would expect it to return `foo`.

Update: The SQL query is generated by Entity Framework Core from C# and I expected the null handling behavior to be translated.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong.  Almost any operation with `NULL` returns `NULL`, including string concatenation.

Comment: `NULL` and an empty string (`’’`) are two different things.

Comment: Technically, if you wanted to do this, you could set `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` off beforehand. But it's like that for a reason, so... (Also this feature will be removed at some point so it's probably wise to not use it.)

Comment: Or use the CONCAT function. It ignores the NULL's

Comment: @LukStorms the code is generated by the EF Core ORM, from C#

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  thanks captain obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can handle the concatenation with NULL by setting CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL as **ON** or **OFF**.

```
PRINT 'Setting CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON';  
GO  
-- SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON and testing.  
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;  
GO  
SELECT 'abc' + NULL ;  
GO  


--SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF and testing.  
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;  
GO  
SELECT 'abc' + NULL;   
GO
```

When the CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is on, it will yield a NULL result, and vice versa.

When this setting is not specified, then the setting of the CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL database option applies.

To view the current setting for this setting, run the following query

```
DECLARE @CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
IF ( (4096 & @@OPTIONS) = 4096 ) SET @CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL = 'ON';  
SELECT @CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL AS CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL;
```

Comment: ["*In a future version of SQL Server `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will always be `ON` and any applications that explicitly set the option to `OFF` will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's the whole concept of `NULL`. It indicates a value that is missing in the database, hence making most operations inapplicable :

- Any arithmetic operation on `NULL` (addition, substraction, multiplication, division on both ends) returns `NULL`.
- String concatenation with `NULL` returns `NULL` (on most RDBMS, but not Oracle, where `NULL` is treated as the empty string, hence a query like `select NULL || 'A' from dual` returns `A`)
- Comparison with `NULL` (equal, different, like) never match. You usually need to use specific functions such as `ISNULL` to test if a value is `NULL`

For more information please have a look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))

Comment: i completely understand the reason behind the described null handling in the case of logical and numeric values, most programming languages treat null the same way, but i was surprised with the `string+` operator specifically.

Comment: Yes @mobal, I agree that this is tricky. Pls note that Oracle RDBMS works differently and happily treats `NULL` as the empty string when used in string concatenation context. Updated my answer with this information.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` doesn't mean "**nothing**" or "**empty**". That's a common misconception. `NULL` really means "**I don't know**". It *might* be empty... but it might be something else; you just don't know what to put there yet.

When you you combine "**foo**" with "**I don't know**", the answer is still "**I don't know**". Pretty much all databases work the same way; it's what the SQL spec requires.